# Unable to load up Swagger-UI page for the RESTEasy Swagger Codegen example

Tags: java, maven, swagger, resteasy

I followed the small tutorial (if it can be called that) [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Server-stub-generator-HOWTO#java-jax-rs-resteasy) to generate server stubs for the petstore example API. I then followed the `readme` instructions in the generated files, which says:

````
To run the server, please execute the following:

```
mvn clean package jetty:run
```

You can then view the swagger listing here:

```
http://localhost:8080/v2/swagger.json
````

The first time I did that, I got a build and compilation error. Apparently the `pom.xml` file was missing *both* the Jetty plugin:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>9.2.9.v20150224</version>
        </plugin>
```

as well as the `swagger-core` dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Although they were mentioned under the `properties` property as follows:

```
<properties>
    <swagger-core-version>1.5.9</swagger-core-version>
    <jetty-version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty-version>
    <resteasy-version>3.0.11.Final</resteasy-version>
    <slf4j-version>1.6.3</slf4j-version>
    <junit-version>4.8.1</junit-version>
    <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
</properties>
```

While I could successfully do `mvn clean package jetty:run` after that:

```
2016-07-28 14:40:11.740:INFO::main: Logging initialized @3196ms
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: swagger-jaxrs-resteasy-server
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src/main/webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = /home/.../restserver/restapi/petstore/jaxrs-resteasy/target/classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /home/.../restserver/restapi/petstore/jaxrs-    resteasy/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/home/.../restserver/restapi/petstore/jaxrs-    resteasy/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = /home/.../restserver/restapi/petstore/jaxrs-    resteasy/src/main/webapp
2016-07-28 14:40:11.799:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.9.v20150224
2016-07-28 14:40:12.430:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@58ba5b30{/,file:/home/.../restserver/restapi/petstore/jaxrs-resteasy/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/home/.../restserver/restapi/petstore/jaxrs-resteasy/src/main/webapp/}
2016-07-28 14:40:12.431:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2016-07-28 14:40:12.450:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started     ServerConnector@6cd64b3f{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-07-28 14:40:12.450:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3906ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

I still receive a 404 when trying to open the site:

$ wget http://localhost:8080/v2/swagger.json

```
--2016-07-28 14:58:42--  http://localhost:8080/v2/swagger.json
Resolving the hostname »localhost (localhost)«... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
http request sent awaiting response... 404 not found
2016-07-28 14:58:42 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

What is going wrong?

EDIT: Here is my `mvn clean package -X jetty:run` output: http://pasted.co/3ceba86c

Comment: please enable the debug logs so that you can find if any thing is going wrong

Comment: I just posted the output from running `mvn clean package -X jetty:run`, but I unfortunately didn't see anything suspicious... I'd appreciate it if someone else could take a look.